# How to run React.js app without react-scripts?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, package.json

My React.js app was created with this command:

> npx create-react-app my-app

Now how can I convert this script section in package.json to run the app without react-scripts?

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "NODE_ENV=development node_modules/react-scripts/bin/react-scripts.js start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

Should it be something like:

> node index.js

How do I convert each option in that scripts section?
Thanks

Comment: What is the purpose of this?

Comment: the whole company applications should be converted.. They do not want to use react-scripts due to some vulnerability issues in react-scripts dependencies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create a React app with `npx create-react-app my-app` you make your react app dependant of react-scripts.

If you no longer want to use this react-scripts who give you a lot of help you can follow [this tutorial](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/alternatives-to-ejecting) *from the official documentation* to eject yourself.

But you can't remove the dependency from an existing project, maybe you are considering to make a new one, and [this tutorial](https://blog.bitsrc.io/create-react-app-without-create-react-app-b0a5806a92) will help you to achieve it !